# Aggregate multiple jquery selectors with common parent

Tags: jquery, parent-child

I have several selectors with a common parent.
Is there a good method to put them under a single function call?
For example:

```
$('td.postbody').children('a[href$=".gif"], a[href$=".jpg"], a[href$=".png"], a[href$=".bmp"]').addClass("zoom2 itag").attr('title','Click to Expand Image.');
$('td.postbody').children('a[href$=".GIF"], a[href$=".JPG"], a[href$=".PNG"], a[href$=".BMP"]').addClass("zoom2 itag").attr('title','Click to Expand Image.');
$('td.postbody').children('a:not([class])').addClass("smlLink");
$('td.postbody').children('img:not([src^="modules/"])').attr("height", "200").addClass("image-link");
```

I'd like to put them under a common function like:

```
$('td.postbody').children('a','img')).each(function(){...});
```

I looked at some of the uses of variables but what I found, didn't look like it would work for this.
My logic is select all the $('td.postbody').children('*') at one time then process the group, rather than scanning the document several times.
Is this good logic for jQuery? Should my approach be different?
Thx,
Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`is`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) method in the loop

```
$('td.postbody').children('a, img').each(function() {
    var el = $(this);
    if (el.is('a[href$=".gif"], a[href$=".jpg"], a[href$=".png"], a[href$=".bmp"]')) {
        // do something
    } else if (el.is('a:not([class])')) {
        // do something
    } else if (el.is('img:not([src^="modules/"])')) {
        // do something
    } 
});
```

... and because selector `[href$=]` is case-sensitive you can check extension by other way:

```
if (!!this.href && /(?:jpg|gif|png|bmp)$/i.test(this.href)) {
}
```

Comment: thx.  This looks like what I was looking for.  I'll give it try. Also, you spotted the the clumsy img detection, thx for that answer too!  You may have also answered a third question, with the else-if the stacking sequence of tests could filter the one of the non-intended results that I spotted last night.  3X results, I like it.

Comment: Worked great.  So far, I've wrapped six selectors into a single call. I checked your solution.  Sorry, I don't have sufficient reputation to + it.   I tried the selector for the images, but couldn't get it to work.  Here's a fiddle if can take a look, working with two selectors.  http://jsfiddle.net/atlbike/cfem6o9b/

Comment: OMG, it's like someone put my old legacy php site on steroids.  I went through and grouped all the jquery calls and stacked them in an semi-optimized order. Grouped so I didn't break any dependencies.  What a difference!

Comment: It seems that I misunderstand your problem: "I tried the selector for the images, but couldn't get it to work". Explain, plz.
This fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/cfem6o9b/5 shows how check extension by regex. I think this way is faster than several `a[href$=".jpg"]`.

Comment: Tut, you understood perfectly. It was my weak coding skill that misunderstood your regex. Which I'll need work on.  Your example fiddle did exactly what I wanted. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

I think single statement is not enough, but you can use some improvements like cache the commonly  used td.postbody selector and also club the 1st and 2nd statements

```
var $tds = $('td.postbody');
$tds.children('a[href$=".gif"], a[href$=".jpg"], a[href$=".png"], a[href$=".bmp"],a[href$=".GIF"], a[href$=".JPG"], a[href$=".PNG"], a[href$=".BMP"]').addClass("zoom2 itag").attr('title','Click to Expand Image.');
$tds.children('a:not([class])').addClass("smlLink");
$tds.children('img:not([src^="modules/"])').attr("height", "200").addClass("image-link");
```